# How do Hertzian dipoles relate to reflection of EM waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, reflection

We recently performed an experiment where the intensity of microwave radiation reflected off different materials was measured. A comment in the script noted that the mechanism by which reflection of EM waves occurs is through the induction of Hertzian dipoles in a material.

Having read up on Hertzian dipoles, I have found nothing which discusses them in the context of reflection. I read that a Hertzian dipole is essentially two small spherical conductors connected by a wire, with charge flowing periodically between them, or something that can be approximated by this. I find it very hard to understand how, for example, a plank of wood would support or even vaguely resemble such a system.

To condense my question, can someone explain how Hertzian dipoles are the mechanism by which EM waves are reflected, or point me to resources that explain this? What bit corresponds to the spheres and which bit to the wire?

Comment: Where did you read this? In general one would have to solve Maxwell's equations to get the correct solutions for scattering (that includes reflection) on a mesoscopic piece of material. For large (i.e. approximately infinite) reflectors one can use ray-optical methods (in optics we assume that optical elements are large compared to the wavelength) and for very small scatterers (molecules in air in case of e.g. Rayleigh scattering) one can assume dipoles. For your case both would be false, however, you probably don't have the mathematical tools to do it "right", hence the "lie to children".

Comment: @CuriousOne Optical ray methods were what we actually used. But our lab manual commented that the mechanism by which EM waves are reflected is through dipoles. But googling Hertzian dipoles, all I can find is stuff relating to electric circuits etc.

Comment: I see...let me put it this way... some textbook authors have a tendency to project that everything in the world is a nail after explaining the function of a hammer. Yes, one can use dipoles (atomic and molecular, not Hertzian, but what the heck) to explain dielectric properties of some materials, but I would strongly urge not to take that explanation too far. A real theory of the interaction of electromagnetic radiation with matter is both complex and it has multiple layers. No, the world is not all nails. On the other hand... it takes several years in university to cover all non-nails...